# How to install pygments on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm following Django-rest-framework.org tutorial and this is the models.py's code as below.

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())
```

and when i run follow command:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

it gives me this error

```
ImportError: No module named pygments.lexers
```

I think that i have to install pygments first to work this code.
So tell me how to install pygments in my Ubuntu 12.04. I have Python 2.7 version installed.

Comment: How did you install DRF? Presumably using pip. You should install pygments the same way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most basically open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> and type `sudo apt-get install python-pygments`. That will work but there is a better way, which I'll explain.

When you're developing a web app you will eventually want to deploy it. You'll want the environment on which you're developing to be as similar to the one on which you deploy as possible. One way to do this is virtual environments. On Ubuntu you also have the option of [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Virtual environments are probably slightly easier if you're just starting out but I would recommend building up to Docker, which is more complete IMO. If you're using Python 3 then you should use [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create your virtual environments. On Python 2 you want [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). These will create an isolated Python environment specific to the project they contain, which means you can have many custom setups for many projects, and you can recreate these relatively easily when deploying to production. When the environment is active you can install python packages with `pip install package-name-here`.

Comment: You're welcome, and please do look into virtual environments and Docker, they'll make your life way easier in the long term :-)

Answer (score 12):

For Python3, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install python3-pygments`

As we traditionally use a virtual environment to run Django, you may also want to install it through pip

Answer (score 4):

I installed via `apt-get install python-pygments` , but it didn't solve my `ImportError: No module named pygments`.

But `pip install Pygments` solved my problem.